# HTML email - mso fallback fonts - where does code go?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I'm creating a HTML email newsletter. I'm using webfonts served by Typekit. It is well documented that versions of Outlook using Microsoft Word to render the email don't use the specified fallback font, but Times New Roman (see https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts).

The work around is to target Outlook and use a different font stack:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type=”text/css”>
h1 {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

My question is: where does this code go?

In the `<head>`?
In the `<body>`?

I'm guessing it goes in the `<head>`, but below the main CSS hence below the `</style>`?

But I've noticed that when I import the code into my Email Service provider (Direct Mail for Mac) strips out this "invisible code". Why is the code between `<!--  -->` surely this makes the code invisible/not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a little confusing, but email clients read if/else statements even if they are hidden by `<!-- -->`.

Email clients interpret this as please do: `<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->` and Outlook interprets it as please ignore. This does just the opposite: `<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><!-- -->`

Example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/5hruzos5/

Outlook Desktop client does not work with most webfonts like Google fonts. Instead of using a fallback font, Outlook will use it's own fallback font, Times New Roman. This is great if you're using a serif font, but if you're not, it can seriously affect the look of your email.

Using if/else, you can target Outlook specifically to use a websafe fallback font by creating a custom style sheet. The preferred location is after the style sheet you use to target all email clients, since the last style listed is the one that gets used. If your email calls for a webfont like Gotham or Lato, this style sheet will direct Outlook to use Arial or a sans-serif font:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css>
  css for email clients
</style>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
  body, table, td, a, h1, p {font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

The reason for the `gte mso9` is that Outlook 2007 (mso version 9 and above) started using Microsoft Word as a formatting engine. This caused compatibility issues with web standards, but helped ensure that a document designed in Word looks appropriate in Outlook email. You can target specific versions of Outlook by using the `mso` number.

An example of if/else in email body:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><!-- -->
starting code for Outlook specific thingy
<![endif]-->

[fallback goes here]

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>ending code if needed<![endif]-->
```

I hope that helps.

Good luck with Outlook.